# Chosen MultiSelect not displaying the pre-selected values in the edit view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, jquery-chosen

```
//MVC View    
<div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.users, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedUsers, Model.Users, new { @class = "chosen-select", multiple = "multiple" })
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".chosen-select").chosen();
        $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
        $(".chosen-select").trigger("liszt:updated");
        $(".chosen-select").chosen().change();
</script>

  //MVC Controller
            model.SelectedUsers = User.Where(x => x.ROLE == 2)
                                 .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                 {
                                     Text = x.Name,
                                     Value = x.Id,
                                 }).ToList();
            model.Users =           User
                                    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = x.Name,
                                        Value = Id,
                                    }).ToList();
```

I have 10 Users and 3 SelectedUsers  which is returned correctly from controller action. 
The create functionality is working correctly but while editing I am not getting the 3 pre-selected users as selected in the chosen ListBox control. when I click on the listBox its showing all the 10 Users.
I tried to implement this using the documentation from http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/
I am not sure if this is the correct syntax or method to do it in the mvc razor view. Any help in the right direction will be really useful thanks..

Comment: The property `SelectedUsers` needs to be `int[]` not `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` If it contains values matching the values in the options, they will be selected.

Comment: It worked as per your suggestion.. @StephenMuecke can you post it as the answer..Thanks a lot for the concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `SelectedUsers` needs to be `int[]` (`or IEnumerable<int>`), not `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

If it contains values matching the values in the options, they will be selected.